# if $Ax=b$ has no solution $\Rightarrow$ $b$ is a linear combination of $A$'s columns.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if $Ax=b$ has no solution $\Rightarrow$ $b$ is a linear combination of $A$'s columns.

I know the statement is false but, please help me understand why.
Thanks

Comment: Write $A$ as columns and see what is $Ax$ in terms of the columns of $A$. It'll give you a nice statement that is true, while being similar in form to the one you're trying to disprove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** let $A$ be a null matrix and think of an appropriate $b$.

Comment: In your case, $b$ must be zeroes as well.

Comment: @AndrePoole Do you understand that you're trying to prove that $P\implies Q$ is false and that to do that, $P$ needs to be true and $Q$ needs to be false?

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I understand: if there's a linear combination then, this combination is a solution, but we said there's no solution. therefore the statement is false. right?

Comment: To prove it is false, you need to find a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solutions and $b$ isn't a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Do you understand this?

Comment: Yes, so for example the null matrix and $b_1,...,b_n \ne 0$.

Comment: @AndrePoole That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Well, by definition of $Ax$ we have $Ax=b$ has a solution iff $b$ is in the column space of $A$.